# Position an element relative to another css element without editing html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, adsense

Is there a way to position an element relative to another element whithout the posibility of editing the html to make one element parent? This is my div order in html which i can't edit. I want "element3" to be positioned relative to "element1", to feet at the half height over "element1". I want my adsense block to be position relative to author position in that empty space on this site: http://www.musicep.com/2013/08/sunlounger-feat-alexandra-badoi-ill-be.html I've tried something like this:

```
#element1 {
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  background: yellow;
  position: relative;
}
 #element2 {
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px; }

#element3 {
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
  position: absolute;
  top:-200px;    }
```

Comment: $("#element3").css("top", $("#element1").css("top"));, same for left

Comment: yes..that's exactly what i want Kierchon. But i can't edit the html.

Comment: Your code works fine dandavis but on my site i have to use id selector (.) not class selector (#) and doesn't work. Any idea why?

Answer (score 1):

U can use property "float" this way:

```
#element1 {
    width: 300px;
    height: 200px;
    background: yellow;
    float: left;
}
#element2 {
    background: blue;
    width: 300px;
    height: 100px;
    float: left; 
}

#element3 {
    width: 300px;
    height: 100px;
    background: red;
    float: left;
}
```

Comment: i think you didn't understand what i want..thank you anyway :)

Answer (score 1):

If you really need it to actually become a child element, and cannot edit the html, you can move things around with jQuery:

```
$('#element1').append($('#element3'));
```

Though keep in mind that moving elements with javascript should usually be a last resort.

Comment: I've tried here http://jsfiddle.net/baM7y/ and works fine but on my site i have to use id selector (.) not class selector (#) and doesn't work. Any idea why?

Comment: You've got that the wrong way around. '#' is used to select an element's ID, and '.' is used to select an elements class. If that is not your problem, then the only issue I could immediately think of would be if you are using classes, and you have more than one of either element with the same class name, then you may have unexpected results. For this operation, you will probably want to ensure that you are using ID's on the elements in question.

Comment: I have more than one element with the same class name. Can you modify somehow the code to work for class selector? Thank you!

Comment: Look on this page to see what i want more clear   http://www.musicep.com/2013/07/bt-aqualung-surrounded.html I have this code: '.publish-info {
height: 150px !important;
position: relative !important;
}

.adsense
{
top:50px !important;
position:absolute !important;
} '

Comment: I want adsense block to fit over publish info in that empty space and i've tried this <script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[ 
window.onload=function(){
$('.publish-info').append($('.adsense'));
}//]]>
</script> but doesn't work

Comment: `$('.publish-info').append($('.adsense-footer .adsense'));` Looking at your source code, there is only one publish info class, and one adsense-footer class, so you can select only the one adsense by specifying it as a child of adsense-footer. I'm not sure why you are using the CDATA tag? And if that doesn't work, you should atleast be  getting an error in your console, please post it if you do.